# How can I fill textboxes using dropdownlist without postback?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, drop-down-menu

I have an asp.net dropDownList listing hours and minutes of the day. I want the time chosen to be shown in a texbox. Can this be done without making a postback?
Thank you
Dov

Comment: I added my own answer and it was deleted by Robert Harvey. Why? It is for me an excellent option! Thank you Dov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the microsoft Ajax control toolkit there's a ComboBox which gives DropDownList and TextBox functions enabling choosing from the ComboBox or writing directly like a TextBox. Also enables limitting independent writing only to items in the ComboBox or entering nonexisting items.

Answer (score 1):

Add an onChange to the drop down and use java script to detect the dropdown selection and write to the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using JavaScript and more specifically [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can set the time client side as shown in this simple example:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            function setTime(){
                var hours = $(".hours").val();
                var mins = $(".minutes").val();
                $(".time").val(hours + ":" + mins );

            };

            $(".hours").change(setTime);
            $(".minutes").change(setTime);

            // call setTime for first view
            setTime();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="time" />

    <select class="hours">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>    
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select class="minutes">
        <option>15</option>
        <option>30</option>    
        <option>45</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

There is a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/swaff/6tq4s/)

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion looks interesting but I don't know java script so I don't know how to implement your idea in my code. I have a dropdownlist that's filled by a loop in the PageLoad event in the c# code. How do I recieve the selected value of the dropDownList and transfer it to the text box, and where in the code do I place the javascript?

Comment: I have added a bit more code to show the reference to jQuery v1.5.1 on the Google content delivery network (CDN) and placed the code snippit in a script tag in the head tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an update panel from ajax control toolkit, if you can use ajax.

It actually creates a postback but partially so end user point of view, seems no postback occures; and your point of view, only the elements in update panel is affected by the postback.